# Bundle Exec is Overwriting Environment Variables

Tags: docker, passenger, bundler

I'm working in a `phusion/passenger-ruby24` Docker image with my Rails application.

My application is in `/<company>/app` and my gems are in `/<company>/app_dependencies`.

When I execute `bundle exec passenger start`, the gems cannot be found (expected). However, when I set `BUNDLE_PATH` in the environment to `/<company>/app_dependencies>`, it doesn't get propagated to the application environment. I can verify this by running `bundle exec 'echo $BUNDLE_PATH'`.

I've been able to bypass this problem by creating a `/<company>/app/.bundle/config` and setting the `BUNDLE_PATH` there. Although it works, it isn't optimal.

I've tried forcing the variable into the app environment like so:

`BUNDLE_PATH=/<company>/app_dependencies bundle exec passenger start`

and

`bundle exec passenger start --envvar BUNDLE_PATH=/<company>/app_dependencies`

without any luck.

Oddly enough, other environment variables get passed though without a problem It's `BUNDLE_PATH` that gets unset. I'm not sure what else to try and although I have some workarounds, I'd like to be able to set the env var which is the more correct way.

Thanks.